# Creating Meteor-friendly id's in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In meteor, when I create an item in a collection, the generated id for the item usually looks like:

```
"_id" : "vxqbpic8yLdc6Ehor"
```

However, when I insert a row directly in Mongo, it's generated id looks like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("549af35926cee46520611838")
```

Is there a way for me to insert data directly into mongo generating an id similar to the way meteor does, or is that something special with meteor?  I'd be happy with just dropping the "ObjectId()" wrap around the value, if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What meteor actually does is create a random 17 character string that consists of characters from within `23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz`

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/random/random.js is what does that. Namely the RandomGenerator.prototype.id(17) function.

So you can include that in your custom code or any other piece of code that generates 17 character random strings from those characters I've given above, and use its outcome as your ID.

In fact, any other random string would suffice, as long as it is universally random, which Meteor's implementation tries to attain.

Comment: I'd paste in the code but it was rather too long and kind of hard to simplify. But go ahead and take it as a whole, it does have some other nice and small utils you can use.

Comment: I was able to see it.  It answered my main concern: is it generating it through another library, or is there a way to specify in mongo to generate an id without making it an ObjectId()

Comment: In fact, yes. You can refer to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#convert-objectids-into-strings for casting ObjectId() to String. You can do `var _id = new ObjectId.valueOf();` get the string part of an id with `ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").valueOf()`

Comment: do these ids need to be random? what is the reasoning behind that? are there security implications to being able to guess an object's id? or do the ids just nee to be unique? i ask because i'm migrating data from a previous system, and it would be much more convenient to id the objects like `post0000000000001`, etc. opposed to generating them randomly...

Comment: They don't need to be random, but be unique. The security implication would be easy guessing of id's for fetching/deleting records for which you can have settings in place in practice, but still the random strings are really hard to guess, so are much better in terms security in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that uses `Math.random()` to generate Meteor Id's:

```
const UNMISTAKABLE_CHARS = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function newMeteorId () {
    return [...Array(17).keys()]
    .map(() => 
        UNMISTAKABLE_CHARS[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * UNMISTAKABLE_CHARS.length)
        ]
    )
    .join('')
}
```

My understanding is that the ids generated using Meteor's `random.js` are more truly random where as this is not but I believe for most use cases this will be sufficiently random.