# do document IDs in Meteor need to be random or just unique?

Tags: meteor

i'm migrating data from a rails system, and it would be really convenient to assign the migrated objects IDs like `post0000000000001`, etc.

i've read here

[Creating Meteor-friendly id's in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641751/creating-meteor-friendly-ids-in-mongo)

that Meteor creates random 17 character strings from

```
23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

which looks to be chosen to avoid possibly ambiguous characters (omits `1` and `I`, etc.)

do the IDs need to be random for some reason? are there security implications to being able to guess a Meteor document's ID?! or it is just an easy way of generating unique IDs?

Mongo seems fine with sequential ids:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

so i would guess this would have to be a Meteor constraint if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

The IDs just need to be unique.

Typically there is an element of order: Such as using integers, or timestamps, or something with sequentiality.

This can't work in Meteor since inserts can come from the client, they may be disconnected for a period, or clients clocks may be off/have varying latency. Also its not possible to know the previous `_id` (in the case of a sequential _id) at the time an _id is written owing to latency compensation (instant inserts).

The consequence of the lack of order in the DDP protocol is the decision to use entirely random ids. That is not to say you can't use your own _ids.

while there is a risk of a collision with this strategy it is minimal on the order of `[number of docs in your collection]/[55^17] * 100 %` or nearly impossible. In the event this occurs the client will temporarily insert it and cancel it once the server confirms the error with a Mongo Duplicate Key error.

Also when it comes to security with the other answer. It is not too much of an issue if the _id of the user is known. It is not possible to log in without a valid hashed login token or retrieve any information with it. This applies to the user collection only of course. If you have your own collection an easily guessable URL containing an id as a reference without publish method checks on the eligibility to read the data is a risk the high entropy random ids generated by Meteor can mitigate.

As long as they are unique it should be ok to use your own ids.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but I suppose Mongo needs a unique ID so when it updates the document, it in fact creates a new version of the document of that same ID.

The real question is - I too whish to know - if we can change the ID without screwing Mongo mechanism and reliability, or we need to create a secondary attribute? (It can make a smaller index too I suppose)?

But me too, I can imagine that security wise, it is better if document IDs are difficult to guess, especially user IDs! Otherwise, could it be easy or possible to fake a user, knowing the ID?  Anybody, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible and desirable to change ID from Mongo.

But you can easily create a autoincrement ID with http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
  var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true
      }
 );

 return ret.seq;
}
```

I have created a package that does just that and that is configurable.
https://atmospherejs.com/stivaugoin/fluid-refno

```
var refNo = generateRefNo({
    name: 'invoices', // default: 'counter'
    prefix: 'I-',  // default: ''
    size: 5, // default: 5
    filling: '0' // default: '0'
});
console.log(refNo); // output: "I-00001"
```

you now can use `refNo` to add in your document on Insert

maybe it will help you