# generate Meteor.JS ObjectID outside of Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, objectid

I'm trying to import a large quantity of data through a NodeJS script into my Meteor App Database using the NodeJS mongoDB driver.

I need to generate a Meteor ObjectID in the script. I know that I can configure my Meteor App to generate Ids as Mongo does, but I would like to avoid to do so because it would imply a lot of changes in my app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Meteor-friendly id's in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641751/creating-meteor-friendly-ids-in-mongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [mongodb driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) in your script to generate ObjectIds as described in the [docs here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ObjectID.html).

Example:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

_id: new ObjectID()
```

Because Meteor use hexadecimal Strings for the IDS you need to use :

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

_id: new ObjectID().toHexString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I tried it already, meteor throw : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids`

Comment: Have you tried using `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` ?

Comment: I'm not in the Meteor app so I can't use the Meteor ObjectID()

Comment: Ok I just found this post : https://github.com/JcBernack/meteor-reactive-aggregate/issues/22 . `ObjectID().toHexString()` works fine ! I will edit your answer

Comment: In the meteor console when I try to fetch the data in my meteor app